# Camera Orientation in Android App

Tags: android, opencv, camera, orientation

I have created an Android app that opens a video stream, extending the class JavaCameraView. The application should capture frames to process them. I have used, to realize this app, the tutorials contained in the OpenCV4Android package (version 2.4.5). I use Eclipse Juno, and my phone is a samsung s4, and surfing the web I realize that my problem is very common on many devices, including galaxy s,s2,s3,s4.

My problem is that my camera, when is opened, in portrait mode results rotated of 90 degrees. It seems to be always in landscape orientation.
I have read somewhere that it is possible to flip camera on the fly, but I have not understood how.
Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Default camera orientation is in landscape mode only. You need to set the parameters on the camera to set the rotation

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
        {   
            parameters .set("orientation", "portrait");
            parameters .set("rotation",90);
        }
        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
        {                               
            parameters .set("orientation", "landscape");          
            parameters .set("rotation", 90);
        }

camera.setParameters(parameters);

or

camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
```

Comment: I can't use this method, because I access camera through opencv and not android, so I have to work with CameraViewBridgeBase mOpenCvCameraView, and not with class Camera.